# Changing a built-in kernel module parameter at booting time?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, nvme

I am trying to change a parameter, called "sgl_threshold", in the nvme driver when booting into Ubuntu 16.04 running linux kernel v4.18-generic.

It appears the nvme driver is actually built-in as it is not found using lsmod and is being used by a device, and also is found in `/sys/module/nvme/`(parameters are found in `/sys/module/nvme/parameters`).

My question is how can I change this built-in module's parameter at runtime, or permanently change this parameter whenever the nvme driver is loaded?

I have tried creating a file in modprobe.d with `nvme sgl_threshold=1`, and also editing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the default grub file.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up figuring this out...

Edit the defualt grub file (/etc/default/grub) at the line beginning with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append `nvme.sgl_threshold=1` within the quotation marks.

Comment: Also need to call 'sudo update-grub' for the change to stick.